# Eigen: vector or matrix componentwise to power?

Tags: eigen, pow

Given a vector of reals `c` and a vector of integers `rw`, I want to create a vector `z` with elements `z_i=c_i^rw_i`. I tried to do this using the component-wise function `pow`, but I get a compiler error.

```
#include <Eigen/Core>

typedef Eigen::VectorXd RealVector;
typedef Eigen::VectorXi IntVector; // dynamically-sized vector of integers
RealVector c; c << 2, 3, 4, 5;
IntVector rw; rw << 6, 7, 8, 9;
RealVector z = c.pow(rw);    **compile error**
```

The compiler error is

```
error C2664: 'const Eigen::MatrixComplexPowerReturnValue<Derived> Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>::pow(const std::complex<double> &) const': cannot convert argument 1 from 'IntVector' to 'const double &'
      with
      [
          Derived=Eigen::Matrix<double,-1,1,0,-1,1>
      ]
c:\auc\sedanal\LammSolve.h(117): note: Reason: cannot convert from 'IntVector' to 'const double'
c:\auc\sedanal\LammSolve.h(117): note: No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
```

What is wrong with this code? And, assuming it can be fixed, how would I do the same operation when c is a real matrix instead of a vector, to compute `c_ij^b_i` for all elements of c?

Compiler is Visual Studio 2015, running under 64-bit Windows 7.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, `MatrixBase::pow` is a function that computes the matrix power of a square matrix (if the matrix has an eigenvalue decomposition, it is the same matrix, but with the eigenvalues raised to the given power).

What you want is an element-wise power, which since there is no `cwisePow` function in `MatrixBase`, requires switching to the `Array`-domain. Furthermore, there is no integer-specialization for the powers (this could be efficient, but only up to a certain threshold -- and checking for that threshold for every element would waste computation time), so you need to cast the exponents to the type of your matrix.

To also answer your bonus-question:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Core>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    Eigen::MatrixXd A; A.setRandom(3,4);
    Eigen::VectorXi b = (Eigen::VectorXd::Random(3)*16).cast<int>();

    Eigen::MatrixXd C = A.array() // go to array domain
        .pow(                 // element-wise power
             b.cast<double>() // cast exponents to double
            .replicate(1, A.cols()).array() // repeat exponents to match size of A
        );

    std::cout << A << '\n' << b << '\n' << C << '\n';
}
```

Essentially, this will call `C(i,j) = std::pow(A(i,j), b(i))` for each `i`, `j`. If all your exponents are small, you might actually be faster than that with a 
simple nested loop that calls a specialized `pow(double, int)` implementation (like gcc's `__builtin_powi`), but you should benchmark that with actual data.

Comment: I was relying on "Catalog of coefficient-wise math functions" (https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__CoeffwiseMathFunctions.html), which says Power functions
a.pow(b);pow(a,b);  raises a number to the given power ( $ a_i ^ {b_i} $)
a and b can be either an array or scalar.  using std::pow;
pow(a[i],b[i]);
(plus builtin for integer types)

Comment: Trying to figure out the same thing :))