# How to use element wise integer power with Eigen

Tags: c++11, eigen

I would like to take the element wise power of an array of double with and array of int using Eigen power function.

Here is a sample code that reproduce the issue using Eigen v3.3.4 and v3.3.7:

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>

int main() {
  Eigen::ArrayXd x(10);
  Eigen::ArrayXd res(10);
  Eigen::ArrayXi exponents(10);
  x = Eigen::ArrayXd::Random(10);
  exponents = Eigen::ArrayXi::LinSpaced(10, 0, 9);
  res = Eigen::pow(x, exponents);

  return (0);
}
```

The error message is quite long but in essence I get

```
YOU_MIXED_DIFFERENT_NUMERIC_TYPES__YOU_NEED_TO_USE_THE_CAST_METHOD_OF_MATRIXBASE_TO_CAST_NUMERIC_TYPES_EXPLICITLY
```

which does not seem appropriate to me in this context, along with

```
Eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/functors/BinaryFunctors.h:294:84: error: no type named ‘ReturnType’ in ‘struct Eigen::ScalarBinaryOpTraits<double, int, Eigen::internal::scalar_pow_op<double, int> >’
   typedef typename ScalarBinaryOpTraits<Scalar,Exponent,scalar_pow_op>::ReturnType result_type;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eigen: vector or matrix componentwise to power?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44268968/eigen-vector-or-matrix-componentwise-to-power)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message indicated, you can't mix scalar types implicitly. You have to explicitly cast so that the types match:

```
res = Eigen::pow(x, exponents.cast<double>());
```

As for a specialization for integer types, the template of the power function (as a functor) is:

```
template<typename ScalarX,typename ScalarY, bool IsInteger = 
                                 NumTraits<ScalarX>::IsInteger&&NumTraits<ScalarY>::IsInteger>
```

and calls a simple `pow(x,y)` unless both types are integers (`IsInteger`), in which case there is a different specialization.

There is also an overload for an array to the power of a constant, which doesn't seem to be what you are looking for. In that case (unless ggael corrects me), you can definitely implement your own `CustomBinaryOp`

Comment: but then it would still use the integer power ?

Comment: No, not at all.

Comment: I am confused, on this page https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__CoeffwiseMathFunctions.html it states there is an implementation of integer power in Eigen. Do you mean that this integer power is restricted to powers of integer with integer exponents ?

Comment: You mean this: “plus builtin for integer types”?

Comment: Yes I do. To use Eigen's vectorization facilities for pow(x, n) where x is double and n is an integer, do you think I can use binaryExpr() or is it hopeless (https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1MatrixBase.html#a1063a3752d30b568e52c89ce4e567489) ? The point is that the integer power of a double is much cheaper than for the general case.

Comment: @FélixMusil Regarding integer-power, there is built-in support for `pow(int,int)` only in Eigen (or any other integer type). Also, whether `pow(double, int)` is actually faster really depends on the magnitude of the integers. You can write your own binary expression. Maybe first try with a manual loop, to see if you are actually faster than `pow(double, double)`. Also, vectorization will be quite difficult with (different) integer powers.